Manga where the MC used reincarnation magic and found out his original body still exist, he was even considered as greatest mage in his time
manga where the MC used reincarnation magic and found out his original body still exist, he was even considered as greatest mage in his time.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  What kind of a society did he live in?  Was his original body still alive, embalmed, magically preserved, or something else?  Could it do anything?

This is Dorei Tensei: Sono Dorei, Saikyou no Moto Ouji ni Tsuki.

Ars, the prince of the Kingdom of Karitz, who was called the strongest wizard, died at a young age. But on the verge of death, he uses reincarnation magic. Reincarnated as Wals Sai, a slave with the best body! Wals, who became the escort of a princess in a small country, became a matchless slave who used her best body and magic to crush all enemies!

The synopsis covers much of the details of the question.
Early on in the story, several years after his reincarnation, he discovers that there was no time gap between his death and rebirth, and that his original body is still alive.

Initially he believes it's only a cover-up of his death, but as I recall he later finds out that his original body is truly alive. I don't believe I read enough of the story to find out the exact circumstances.
